# How do u ensure that a method call(JNI Call)inside a thread inside OnPreviewFrame() is finished before being called again

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This question is related to Android multi-threading, OpenCV and JNI. The JNI call made inside onCameraFrame is kind of an expensive image-processing operation, hence the camera-preview frame rate gets very slow (a lot of frame lag). When, the native method - 'FindSquare' is called in background from a new thread, the performance improves a little but not very much.

Please suggest the most efficient way to do what I intend to do below, so as to improve the frame-rate.

```
boolean isCallFinished = false;
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {

    Size originalSize = inputFrame.size();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, mDstImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);

    Imgproc.resize(inputFrame, mDstImg, new Size(mScreenWidth,
            mScreenHeight)); // 2048, 1536

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Message msg = new Message();
            if(!isCallFinished) {                              
                msg.arg1 = FindSquares(mDstImg.getNativeObjAddr()); // JNI call
                isCallFinished = true;
                messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }).start();


    if (mDraw == 1) {
        Imgproc.resize(mDstImg, inputFrame, originalSize);
    }
    return inputFrame;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A rapid optimization on a first glance would be to avoid creating a new thread for each frame.

Creating a new thread is very expensive.

Try the following approach :

- Create a worker thread (keep reference to it)
- Create a synchronized queue to communicate with the worker thread
- Add objects to the worker thread queue and process them as a bunch

I'll try to write down the concept bellow , and adapt it to your needs (please note that the code wasn't tested in a proper environment).

```
public class MyWorkerThread extends Thread
{
ArrayList<FrameEvent> frameList;
boolean runWorkerThread;

public WorkerThread
{
    super("FrameEventsWorkerThread");
    runWorkerThread=true;
    frameList= new ArrayList<FrameEvent>();
}

public synchronized AddFrameEvent(FrameEvent aEvent)
{
    frameList.add(aEvent);
}

public void kill ()
{
    runWorkerThread=true;
}
public void run()
{
    while (true && runWorkerThread)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            if (frameList.size()>0)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<frameList.size();i++)
                {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    if (!isCallFinished) { // don't quite understand what you want with this
                        FrameEvent evt = frameList.get(i);
                        msg.arg1 = FindSquares(evt.dstImg.getNativeObjAddr());
                        isCallFinished=true;
                        messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
                frameList.clear();
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
 }
}
```

Your new function should look something like this :

```
boolean isCallFinished = false;
MyWorkerThread theThread;

public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {

Size originalSize = inputFrame.size();
Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame, mDstImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);

Imgproc.resize(inputFrame, mDstImg, new Size(mScreenWidth,
        mScreenHeight)); // 2048, 1536

FrameEvent newEvt = new FrameEvent();
newEvt.dstImg = mDstImg;
theThread.AddFrameEvent(newEvt); // avoid creating new threads


if (mDraw == 1) {
    Imgproc.resize(mDstImg, inputFrame, originalSize);
}
return inputFrame;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this. I understand that creating new thread each time would be expensive. Meanwhile, I was also looking up how could I re-use a single thread. Seems like ExecutorService is also an option. Any suggestions on this? 
"isCallFinished" (a boolean flag) was my naive way of ensuring that the JNI method is not called multiple times even before it returns/completes.

Comment: Use the Worker Thread Code I wrote above in order to avoid thread spawning. It will hold for what you need (re-using a single thread). You can make it a singleton and you can use it across your program by implementing different message types.